# Javascript undefined object values

Tags: javascript, undefined

I encounter an undefined on associative array values, and cant figure out why!

```
var list = new Array();

function addNewElement(id, n) {
    var obj = new Object();
    obj["id"] = id;
    obj["n"] = n;
    list.push(obj);
}

function exists(id) {
    for (var o in list) {
        if (o["id"] == id) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

id is string, n is an integer.

In exists o["id"] returns Undefined, for every object in it, but direct after object creation the values are present and accessible via obj["id"].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not how JS for loops work. Your `o` variable becomes the index, not the value. It should be:

```
if (list[o]["id"] == id) {
```

Except really you shouldn't use a `for..in` on an array, so it should be:

```
function exists(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i]["id"] == id) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Hm, could you link me to an explanation why JS does not use arrays like almost every other language? (Array[index] is afaik the normal way of accessing arrays?)

Comment: Yes, `arrayName[index]` _is_ what JS does. Where you said `Array[index]` in your comment, `Array` would be your `list` variable and `o` would be the `index`, hence `list[o]` as shown in my answer gets you the object at that array location and `list[o]["id"]` (or `list[o].id`) gets you a property of the object at that array location. For reference: [MDN's `for..in` page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Comment: Aw i see, but it is never the less quite non-intuitive behaviour if you come from e.g Java where for(Object o : list) uses an Iterator and returns you the actual object in o, allowing direct access. So javascript for..in is somewhat similar to the iterators in C++ STL.

Comment: Yes. There is an array [`.forEach()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) that behaves the way you are expecting where you'd get the actual object in `o`, but it'd be clunkier to use for your purpose where you want to return out of the containing function as soon as you find a matching value. Also the JS `for..in` is handy if you need both the key name and the associated value - it's not intended for arrays.

Answer (score -1):

> Below is also awesome code snippet : [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/g4PPu/1/)

```
 var list = {};
    setValue("etshte", 393);
    var result = containsKey("etshte");
    alert(result);

    function setValue(key, value) {
        list[key] = value;
    }

    function containsKey(key) {
        if (list[key] == undefined)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

[Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/g4PPu/1/)

Comment: That's not an appropriate use of an array, though it works because arrays are a type of object. In your code `list` should be a plain object, as in `var list = {};`. (Note that when I say "it works", it doesn't actually do what the OP was trying as far as creating a list of objects with `id` and `n` properties. Also `list[key] == undefined` is kind of imprecise: what if a property with the specified key has been created but its value is `undefined` or `null`? That's not the same as the key not existing at all.)

Comment: i used array only because it was used in question

Answer (score -2):

For in loops not only cycle through added members, but also those stored in the prototype

To fix this use:

```
if (o.hasOwnProperty("id") && o["id"] == id) { /* */ }
```

Comment: Okay didnt know that - makes me wonder why i should use for..in anyway? in that case i just stick to good old for loops instead!

Comment: The fact that `for-in` includes inherited properties really has nothing to do with what's causing the issue. Using `o.hasOwnProperty()` won't fix anything because `o` is a string.

Comment: Yes right but good to know anyway - he issue remains thats right.the object exists but the contents of o["id"] are undefined, as if i never created the key-value!

Comment: On the first iteration of the loop `o` will be the string `"0"`, the _index_ of the first array element. It will not be the object stored at that index. On the second iteration `o` will be `"1"`, the second _index_.